# Material UI Cards subttitle introduces Horizontal Scroll bar

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I face this issue for Cards that when the Subtitle becomes long the card starts a Horizontal scroll bar before breaking into next Line. Any way this can be solved? Please see the demo of what I am talking here...

[image: Edit Material-UI]

I would ideally like the Subtitle to break without the horizontal scrolling, any help would be appreciated.. thanks

Comment: did you apply styles to card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will fix your problem. You just need to fix the strange `padding-right: 90px` to`div` in `card-header`.

```
<CardHeader className="card-header" /*Your next attributes*/ />

.card-header{
  display: flex;
}
```